# Suspend sometimes doesn't work completely.

Tags: 16.04, suspend

This has been happening often lately but not all of the time. When I go to suspend my pc, the fans and led stay on, but not the display. Only way to fix it is turning it off and back on, but that completely defeats the purpose. 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I've seen hardware (laptops, desktop & other) that keep their fans running when suspended because of [room] temperature.  Some turn their fans off after a short while (I assume by motherboard when cooler as OS is suspended).  If its during warmer [room, heaters?] weather I'd wonder if its hardware related (from my observation anyway)

Comment: Same here. This happened on my Windows 10 install, and continues to occur on Kubuntu as well. Sounds like a hardware in my case maybe. What make/model is your machine? Mine is a HP 15 TouchSmart f010dx.

Comment: Same. after recently update this happened.

Answer (score 1):

The suspend function is accomplished through a mix of hardware and software. As @guiverc mentioned, the hardware may have determined that fans need to continue to run during suspend. For example, if the machine was near overheating at the time of suspend, some continued cooling may be called for even after the CPU is put to sleep.

@M_W has a good idea to check if you are wondering whether an issue is caused by software or hardware-- test with a second operating system on the same hardware and see if you get the same result.

On the hardware side, you can review your power management settings in the BIOS. On the software side. Since few details were provided about the nature of the problem, starting with general guide [troubleshooting suspend issues on Linux](https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues) is recommended.

Comment: I don't know if it's a hardware issue, I don't think anything should be overheating, the pc is rather cool, if not just cold. But I guess that could be the case.

Edit: Sorry I pressed enter meaning to make a second paragraph. Anyway, it seems to be consistent that whenever this happens, I look on the update manager to find ubuntu base update. But this happens every other day. Could that be the cause?